# Transform and load values from a .txt file to Oracle table | unix | Oracle

Tags: oracle, unix, etl, sql-loader

Well let us say that I have the following file .txt containing 3 rows in total:

```
cat my_file_to_load.txt

993408
Sep 01 12:46:46 2017
Sep 01 12:46:51 2017
```

The file is an extraction of specific data from a huge log file.
First row is the number of success_rows, second row is the start_time and the third one is the end_time.
My requirement in this case is to "format" the data accordingly in order to load it to an oracle table defined by below script:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC.TEST_PP
(
  SUCCESS_ROWS  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  START_TIME    VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  END_TIME      VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
)
```

What my ideal output would look alike in the table (we have multiple .txt files, so each row will be depicted like below):

```
SUCESS_ROWS    START_TIME            END_TIME
993408         01/09/2017 12:46:46  01/09/2017 12:46:51
```

As far as I am concerned, I will use sqlldr to load them.
I understand that I must create accordingly a .ctl file to define the relevant info.

Could you kindly help me on how to transform accordingly the data in the .txt file in order to load them to the aforementioned table?

Any help would be really much appreciated :)

Thank you very much for your time, have a good day.

Comment: can you add a character at the end of each row (eg. a comma ',')?

Comment: yes this is feasible (allowed)

Answer (score 0):

At moment I found this solution.  It needs you add a fixed character at the end of every line (eg. a comma ',').
I named data file test3.csv and named ctl file TEST3.CTL.

**Command line:**

```
sqlldr ERRORS=100000 userid=xxx/yyy control=TEST3.CTL data=test3.csv log=test3.log bad=test3.bad skip=0
```

**CTL**

```
LOAD DATA  
CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1  
APPEND 
CONCATENATE 3
INTO TABLE TEST_PP 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS  
(  
SUCCESS_ROWS ,  
START_TIME  ,  
END_TIME  
)
```

**Sample data file:**

```
993408,
Sep 01 12:46:46 2017,
Sep 01 12:46:51 2017,
993412,
Sep 02 10:22:46 2017,
Sep 02 11:44:51 2017,
```

Output table:

```
993408  Sep 01 12:46:46 2017    Sep 01 12:46:51 2017
993412  Sep 02 10:22:46 2017    Sep 02 11:44:51 2017
```

**Log file**

```
Table TEST_PP, loaded from every logical record.
Insert option in effect for this table: APPEND
TRAILING NULLCOLS option in effect

   Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
SUCCESS_ROWS                        FIRST     *   ,       CHARACTER            
START_TIME                           NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER            
END_TIME                             NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER            


Table TEST_PP:
  2 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.


Space allocated for bind array:                  49536 bytes(64 rows)
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:             2
Total logical records rejected:         0
Total logical records discarded:        0

Run began on Wed Sep 06 12:17:55 2017
Run ended on Wed Sep 06 12:17:55 2017

Elapsed time was:     00:00:00.08
CPU time was:         00:00:00.01
```

Comment: Ok ok, etsa, a valid one !! wow thanks.. But if commas are not allowed at end of each row?

Moreover should I not covert the format of date accordingly so to be loaded into the table?